# Swift: How to declare a property with classes' names

Tags: swift

For example, this snippet is taken from `UIColor` definition in Swift:

```
// Access the underlying CGColor or CIColor.
public var CGColor: CGColor { get }
```

However attempting to do the same for, let's say `NSError`, in my own class causes an error:

```
public class MyClass {
    public var NSError: NSError {
        return NSError(domain: "mydomain", code: 0, userInfo: [:])
    }
}
```

The `var` line shows `Use of undeclared type 'NSError'`.

**Is this still possible? What's a good way to do this?**

<sub>Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.1 clang-703.0.29)

Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9</sub>

Comment: confirmed with simple `Foo` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do this by creating a `typealias` for `NSError`, `NSErrorRef`. You would then refer to this typealias throughout your class, as `NSError` would now refer to a property, not a class.

```
public typealias NSErrorRef = NSError
```

```
public class MyClass {
    public var NSError:NSErrorRef {
        return NSErrorRef(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

However, I would *never* recommend this.

I suspect the only reason that `CGColor` is named that way in the Swift header of `UIColor` is simply to preserve interoperability with Objective-C. As for why it works without any confusing errors – I can't say. Although, if you actually look in the docs of `UIColor`, you'll see [`CGColor` is actually listed as `cgColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIColor/CGColor) (when Swift is selected) – which shows even Apple thinks it isn't defined correctly!

In any case, convention states that properties should start with a lowercase letter (in order to prevent this kind of confusion in the first place). So you could do this instead:

```
public class MyClass {
    public var nsError:NSError {
        return NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

Or even better, you could just name your property `error` – as prefixes should be seldom used in Swift anyway (unless you need to disambiguate – which you actually appear to need to do in your case).

```
public class MyClass {
    public var error:NSError {
        return NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: The class is actually an error class so a plain `error` property does not makes much sense. I want to provide accessor to obtain `NSError` thus the question. Anyway, thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: @chakrit Ah well `nsError` then makes perfect sense in that situation in order to disambiguate. Happy to be of help :)